# Showing certian categories first while iterating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Currently I order my categories by doing `"categories": category.objects.order_by('-title')` I want to have full control over what order each object appears. I was thinking of having a `rank` attribute `rank = models.IntegerField()` however I feel like there could be 2 category objects with a rank of '1' which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide more than 1 value to `order()` method. It means that, objects which have same value for order parameter,they will reordering according to next parameter.